# Countdown hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a time value for today. I need to have a countdown showing how many hours and minutes left till that time. And I need this countdown to update minutes while the user is on the page.

I did a quick search and see a lot of plugins, but I thougt this could be quite simple without additional scripts.

```
Time left <span class="remainingTime"></span>

var day = new Date(),
    now = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes(),
    end = '23:00';
```

I guess I need some sort of conversion, perhaps to milliseconds to get initial time to show, and then perhaps setTimeout and decrement by 60000?

Comment: Well... have you tried your suggestion? How'd you get on with that? Did it do what you wanted?

Comment: That's my theoretical brainstorming. I'm lost so far...

Comment: Write it out, and if it doesn't work and you can't fix the console errors, we will at least be closer to helper you already.

Comment: Yeh like Goose said, give it a whirl mate and let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? small and simple.

```js
function SetTimer(hours, minutes){

    var end = new Date();
    end.setHours(hours);
    end.setMinutes(minutes);

    var secondsLeft = (end - new Date()) / 60000;
    var hoursLeft = Math.floor(secondsLeft / 60);
    var minutesLeft = Math.round(secondsLeft % 60);
    
    $('.remainingTime').text(hoursLeft + ' : ' + minutesLeft);
}

SetTimer(23, 59);

setInterval(function(){
    SetTimer(23, 59);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Time left <span class="remainingTime"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a million and one Google results that show Javascript hours/minute countdown scripts. I found this script in 10 seconds and made it work in 30 seconds. You should really do more research before asking next time. Here's a script from one of the first results:

```
function DaysHMSCounter(initDate, id){
    this.counterDate = new Date(initDate);
    this.container = document.getElementById(id);
    this.update();
}

DaysHMSCounter.prototype.calculateUnit=function(secDiff, unitSeconds){
    var tmp = Math.abs((tmp = secDiff/unitSeconds)) < 1? 0 : tmp;
    return Math.abs(tmp < 0 ? Math.ceil(tmp) : Math.floor(tmp));
}

DaysHMSCounter.prototype.calculate=function(){
    var secDiff = Math.abs(Math.round(((new Date()) - this.counterDate)/1000));
    this.days = this.calculateUnit(secDiff,86400);
    this.hours = this.calculateUnit((secDiff-(this.days*86400)),3600);
    this.mins = this.calculateUnit((secDiff-(this.days*86400)-(this.hours*3600)),60);
    this.secs = this.calculateUnit((secDiff-(this.days*86400)-(this.hours*3600)-(this.mins*60)),1);
}

DaysHMSCounter.prototype.update=function(){ 
    this.calculate();
    this.container.innerHTML =
        " <strong>" + this.days + "</strong> " + (this.days == 1? "day" : "days") +
        " <strong>" + this.hours + "</strong> " + (this.hours == 1? "hour" : "hours") +
        " <strong>" + this.mins + "</strong> " + (this.mins == 1? "min" : "mins") +
        " <strong>" + this.secs + "</strong> " + (this.secs == 1? "sec" : "secs");
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){self.update();}, (1000));
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<div id="myCounter"></div>

<script>
new DaysHMSCounter('December 25, 2015 00:00:00', 'myCounter');
</script>
```

**[TRY DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rcj8rayt/)**

I'm sure you can modify it to remove the 'days' and 'seconds' part.